# duplicate individual paragraphs in txt file

Tags: python, text, repeat

I have a programme in which I need to duplicate each individual block of text multiple times so that it repeats. This is what I have.

```
echo update
echo snapshot
echo gall
echo clearobj
echo read rot_003.speck

echo update
echo snapshot
echo gall
echo clearobj
echo read rot_004.speck
```

except there are 150 rot_"n".speck files, giving 150 individual paragraphs, so doing this manually is not possible. The form I need the data in is as follows:

```
echo update
echo snapshot
echo gall
echo clearobj
echo read rot_003.speck

echo update
echo snapshot
echo gall
echo clearobj
echo read rot_003.speck

echo update
echo snapshot
echo gall
echo clearobj
echo read rot_003.speck

echo update
echo snapshot
echo gall
echo clearobj
echo read rot_004.speck

echo update
echo snapshot
echo gall
echo clearobj
echo read rot_004.speck

echo update
echo snapshot
echo gall
echo clearobj
echo read rot_004.speck
```

Is there a simple code for this. Preferably in python if possible. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to (your second question on) StackOverflow. Your question is not clear, especially regarding the formats of your input and output files. How many times should each block in the output file repeat? Are all the numbers from `003` through `152` used once in the input file? Are the numbered lines the only lines that differ between the blocks? And so on. Please clarify. Also, what code attempts have you made on this problem, and just where are you stuck? You need to show some of your work so we know you are not just dumping your homework on us.

Comment: Please  include your current python code in the question. It's unclear exactly what you need help figuring out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
for i in range(0,150):
    print("echo update \necho snapshot \necho gall \necho clearobj")
    print("echo read rot_"+"%03d"%i+".speck \n")
```

`"%03d"%a` in Python2 converts to a three digit string.

Comment: This puts the numbered lines only once each in the output file, while the example output shows that the OP wants those numbered lines in repeated blocks. You really should not answer such a vague question, since the OP never states how many repetitions are wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! You should first explore how to [read and write to text files in python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python). Focus on the sections that deal with splitting and working with lines. Experiment with these statements on one or two paragraphs in your file.

Ask yourself: Can I read the first paragraph by accessing the file line by line until I reach a condition? Can I manipulate the fact that each paragraph is separated by a newline character (`\n`) or that each paragraph is of a fixed length?